# How to determine which physics object ended contact in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I've been trying to call a method in the method `didEndContact:contact` when a player jumps off a certain physics object called `"triFloor"`, how would I run a method in `didEndContact:contact` only when the players contact with `"trifFloor"` ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't run didEndContact: just between player and trifFoor (unless those are the only two with physics body), you run the method every time and in the method, find who it made contact with and do the appropriate actions.

```
- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

    if ((contact.bodyA == player && contact.bodyB == trifFoor) ||
        (contact.bodyA == trifFoor && contact.bodyB == player)) {
        //Do what you want here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I not just check for bodyA and bodyB to == triFloor?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You want to handle the contact between two triFloor objects?

Comment: well from my understanding this method get called every time a contact ends, so hence the face you'd check if `(contact.bodyA == triFloor || contact.bodyB == triFloor)`

Comment: Yes, but testing it like that doesn't guarantee that it was between PLAYER and triFloor. If you have an enemy for example, you're if-true block would be executed for the enemy-triFloor contact as well.

Comment: I think I remember Simone Allardice explaining you can't track which of bodyA or bodyB contacted whom first. SpriteKit apparently has some way of calculating this but access to this information is supposedly restricted to the developer/programmer.